# zoom image using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am looking for a jQuery image zoom script with functonality as like in [this link](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/demo/magento/index.php/chair.html).
Has anyone done this before?

I am looking for scripts  which supports with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try:**

[jQuery plugin : Fancy Zoom](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jquery-fancyzoom/)

[Download Fancy Zoom](http://www.dfc-e.com/sites/pages/upload/01_opensource/fancyzoom-1.5.tar.gz)

---

**You can also try:**

- http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/image-zoom/
- http://addyosmani.com/blog/zoomer-gallery-a-jquery-plugin-for-displaying-images-with-flash-like-zooming-effects/
- http://mattbango.com/demos/hover-zoom/

**EDIT:**

[ASP.NET image zoom implementation](http://www.levitical.org/post/ASPNET-image-zoom-implementation.aspx)

[A Plugin for zoom with Mouse Scroll Wheel](http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/index_it.html)

Comment: i am looking for the functionality like when scrolling using mouse then the  image should enlarge as like i have refered with the link above

Answer (score 0):

They're using [AJAX Zoom](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/). It isn't too difficult to implement, although it does require more than just jQuery (PHP 5.3?) if I remember correctly. Anyways, check it out.

Comment: Alright, that wasn't clarified originally. Possibly something like http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo1 then?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It's exactly what you need -

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajax-zoom

Hope this helps.